# WiFi not working after my laptop lid is closed

Tags: wireless, internet, laptop, hp, 18.04

My laptop doesn't hibernate but WiFi is not working properly on my laptop after my laptop lid is closed,my laptop is connected to an external display through HDMI . Ubuntu Version 18.04

Comment: could be interference from something at the bottom of your laptop in the touchpad area, which interferes with the Wi-Fi aerial usually placed at the top of the lid next to the webcam. I doubt that is the case though.

Comment: but it works fine with lid closed on windows 10

Comment: @Divyam got the same problem, did you mange to solve it?

Comment: @Bender Nope. I think Tooniis is right that it's occurring because of placement if the WIFI aerial in the laptop.